# How can I download files from a private repo with ssh for bitbucket/github?

Tags: python, github, ssh, bitbucket, paramiko

I have looked through docs and cannot find anywhere an example of how this might be achieved.

This question relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047296/pyinstaller-updater-with-github-bitbucket-private-repos), in that I want to distribute updates but only to those that have a ssh key rather than using simple auth.

It works by looking at versions.gz file and then getting the most recent download.  Is this possible with ssH?

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
##ssh://git@bitbucket.org/Tysondogerz/ssh/downloads
ssh.connect('104.192.143.2', 8080, username='https://bitbucket.org/Tysondogerz/ssh/downloads/', password="", key_filename='C:\\Users\\Django\\.ssh\\id_rsa')
#TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Is there a way to authenticate others to download updates from my repository, or is this just a limitation of bitbucket and you must use public repo’s and to use private repo's give out your password with basic auth and cross fingers.

Comment: That's a very strange username you're using in your `ssh.connect` call. Nevertheless, this is an interesting question even if it isn't asked very well.

Comment: The error is suggesting the network error. Also - I think you are confusing two protocols here `ssh` and `https`. I believe you want people to be able to download releases in a private repo only with valid keys right?

Comment: @gabhijit That is correct.  Oauth2 and simple auth require others to have your login and pass and ssh does not work at all it seems

Comment: @gabhijit What solution had you in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Right from 2009](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2009/04/12/new-feature-downloads/), the download feature was described as:

> If a repository is private, the URL for downloading a file will look a bit different (it will include an authentication token that is good for 24 hours),

You cannot use ssh with username/password, as you don't have an account on the remote server (only 'git' has one).

You can see a download process in "[Deploy build artifacts to Bitbucket Downloads](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-build-artifacts-to-bitbucket-downloads-872124574.html)"

Comment: This is very useful. I am having trouble getting it to work with python requests, but I did manage to get it work with Curl so it works at least