# Redirect with no auth

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-requests, bitbucket, urllib

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html), it should be as simple as:

```
data = self.http_pool.urlopen('GET', file_url,
                              preload_content=False,
                              retries=max_download_retries) 



request.add_unredirected_header(key, header)
Add a header that will not be added to a redirected request.
```

But I cannot seem to find any examples on how this can be achieved.

I am using the pyupdater to download updates from bitbucket and launch the newest version of exe.  I am using this library to create a script that connects to bitbucket fine, but then it later redirects to Amazon with `nauthorization: Basic <redacted>\r\n\r\n` (this is bitbucket auth) meaning I get `'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'`.  Amazon does not support basic auth. This should be easily solvable, but I cannot find much on this issue.

The solutions presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161651/authenticates-then-redirects-then-gives-400-bad-request?noredirect=1&lq=1), require Recreating each redirected request manually.  This would become an ever-growing list and get tedious very quickly, if I had to do this for new file I uploaded.  It also does not continue the rest of the script, but rather downloads to the same directory.

As this is how Pyupdater handles the downloads this is where the [issue](https://github.com/JMSwag/PyUpdater/blob/master/pyupdater/client/downloader.py) would likely be solved.

Line 366 of downloader.py:

```
data = self.http_pool.urlopen('GET', file_url,
                                              preload_content=False,
                                              retries=max_download_retries)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this so it no longer creates this error.

Full Error (ctrl f -> 400):

```
Python main.py
DEBUG:root:Version - 2.5.1
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:PyUpdater Version 2.5.1
Current version is  1.3
{'authorization': 'Basic <redacted>'}
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Setting up directories...
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Downloading key file
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Url for request: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/ brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/keys.gz
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.bitbucket.org
send: b'GET /2.0/repositories/ brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/keys.gz HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.bitbucket.org\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nauthorization: Basic <redacted>\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n'
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://api.bitbucket.org:443 "GET /2.0/repositories/brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/keys.gz HTTP/1.1" 302 0
DEBUG:urllib3.util.retry:Incremented Retry for (url='https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/keys.gz'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
INFO:urllib3.poolmanager:Redirecting https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/ brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/keys.gz -> https://bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com/a0e395b6-0c54-4efb-9074-57ec4190020b/downloads/3fc0be6d-ca69-42d3-9711-fbb5cfd2bc38/keys.gz?Signature=<redacted>&Expires=1515976464&AWSAccessKeyId=<redacted>&versionId=n.ymY11KRkq36Xozy25aChvfUT.YzTf5&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22keys.gz%22
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com
header: Server header: Vary header: Content-Type header: X-OAuth-Scopes header: Strict-Transport-Security header: Date header: Location header: X-Served-By header: ETag header: X-Static-Version header: X-Content-Type-Options header: X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes header: X-Credential-Type header: X-Render-Time header: Connection header: X-Request-Count header: X-Frame-Options header: X-Version header: Content-Length send: b'GET /a0e395b6-0c54-4efb-9074-57ec4190020b/downloads/3fc0be6d-ca69-42d3-9711-fbb5cfd2bc38/keys.gz?Signature=<redacted>&Expires=1515976464&AWSAccessKeyId=<redacted>&versionId=n.ymY11KRkq36Xozy25aChvfUT.YzTf5&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22keys.gz%22 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nauthorization: Basic <redacted>\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /a0e395b6-0c54-4efb-9074-57ec4190020b/downloads/3fc0be6d-ca69-42d3-9711-fbb5cfd2bc38/keys.gz?Signature=<redacted>&Expires=1515976464&AWSAccessKeyId=<redacted>&versionId=n.ymY11KRkq36Xozy25aChvfUT.YzTf5&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22keys.gz%22 HTTP/1.1" 400 None
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Resource URL: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/keys.gz
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Got content length of: None
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Content-Length not in headers
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Callbacks will not show time left or percent downloaded.
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Using file as storage since the file is too large
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Block size: 1036
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:{'total': None, 'downloaded': 519, 'status': 'downloading', 'percent_complete': '-.-%', 'time': '--:--'}
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:{'total': None, 'downloaded': 519, 'status': 'finished', 'percent_complete': '-.-%', 'time': '00:00'}
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Download Complete
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:No hash to verify
WARNING:pyupdater.client.downloader:Downloaded file is very large, reading it in to memory may crash the app
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Failed to decompress gzip file
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Version file download failed
header: x-amz-request-id header: x-amz-id-2 header: Content-Type header: Transfer-Encoding header: Date header: Connection header: Server {'authorization': 'Basic <redacted>'}
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Not a gzipped file (b'<?')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyupdater\client\__init__.py", line 440, in _get_key_data
    decompressed_data = _gzip_decompress(data)
  File "C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dsdev_utils\helpers.py", line 58, in gzip_decompress
    data = decompressed_file.read()
  File "C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Lib\gzip.py", line 276, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Lib\gzip.py", line 463, in read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
  File "C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Lib\gzip.py", line 411, in _read_gzip_header
    raise OSError('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'<?')
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Loading version file...
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Downloading online version file
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Url for request: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/ brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/versions.gz
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.bitbucket.org
send: b'GET /2.0/repositories/ brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/versions.gz HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.bitbucket.org\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nauthorization: Basic <redacted>\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n'
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://api.bitbucket.org:443 "GET /2.0/repositories/brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/versions.gz HTTP/1.1" 302 0
DEBUG:urllib3.util.retry:Incremented Retry for (url='https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/versions.gz'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
INFO:urllib3.poolmanager:Redirecting https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/versions.gz -> https://bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com/a0e395b6-0c54-4efb-9074-57ec4190020b/downloads/0b04c4a8-dd59-49d2-9cd7-95d22379a5e6/versions.gz?Signature=<redacted>&Expires=1515976465&AWSAccessKeyId=<redacted>&versionId=jLhOcIbVAU4xRghD3kB2NfB4iLqUr7PM&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22versions.gz%22
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com
header: Server header: Vary header: Content-Type header: X-OAuth-Scopes header: Strict-Transport-Security header: Date header: Location header: X-Served-By header: ETag header: X-Static-Version header: X-Content-Type-Options header: X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes header: X-Credential-Type header: X-Render-Time header: Connection header: X-Request-Count header: X-Frame-Options header: X-Version header: Content-Length send: b'GET /a0e395b6-0c54-4efb-9074-57ec4190020b/downloads/0b04c4a8-dd59-49d2-9cd7-95d22379a5e6/versions.gz?Signature=<redacted>&Expires=1515976465&AWSAccessKeyId=<redacted>&versionId=jLhOcIbVAU4xRghD3kB2NfB4iLqUr7PM&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22versions.gz%22 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nauthorization: Basic <redacted>\r\n\r\n'
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /a0e395b6-0c54-4efb-9074-57ec4190020b/downloads/0b04c4a8-dd59-49d2-9cd7-95d22379a5e6/versions.gz?Signature=<redacted>&Expires=1515976465&AWSAccessKeyId=<redacted>&versionId=jLhOcIbVAU4xRghD3kB2NfB4iLqUr7PM&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22versions.gz%22 HTTP/1.1" 400 None
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Resource URL: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/versions.gz
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Got content length of: None
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Content-Length not in headers
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Callbacks will not show time left or percent downloaded.
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Using file as storage since the file is too large
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Block size: 1036
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:{'total': None, 'downloaded': 519, 'status': 'downloading', 'percent_complete': '-.-%', 'time': '--:--'}
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:{'total': None, 'downloaded': 519, 'status': 'finished', 'percent_complete': '-.-%', 'time': '00:00'}
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Download Complete
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:No hash to verify
WARNING:pyupdater.client.downloader:Downloaded file is very large, reading it in to memory may crash the app
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Failed to decompress gzip file
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Version file download failed
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Not a gzipped file (b'<?')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyupdater\client\__init__.py", line 417, in _get_manifest_from_http
    decompressed_data = _gzip_decompress(data)
  File "C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dsdev_utils\helpers.py", line 58, in gzip_decompress
    data = decompressed_file.read()
  File "C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Lib\gzip.py", line 276, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Lib\gzip.py", line 463, in read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
  File "C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Lib\gzip.py", line 411, in _read_gzip_header
    raise OSError('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'<?')
DEBUG:dsdev_utils.paths:Changing to Directory --> C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\any\main
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Found version file on file system
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Loaded version file from file system
DEBUG:dsdev_utils.paths:Moving back to Directory --> C:\Users\Django\privacy 4
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Data type: <class 'bytes'>
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:App key is None
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Version Data:
{'latest': {'main': {'stable': {'win': '1.4.0.2.0'}}}, 'updates': {'main': {'1.3.0.2.0': {'win': {'file_hash': '807c743b8c29f0053f4f9d9e6a8895b0e037f77480e7065c1470c2aba1cb08a0', 'file_size': 12194381, 'filename': 'main-win-1.3.zip', 'patch_hash': '29fec1006c2736eb78cc859f89e165af942daae6d9ac994a1a686d9b7b418ef6', 'patch_name': 'main-win-5', 'patch_size': 147}}, '1.4.0.2.0': {'win': {'file_hash': 'd59a22a95229f0a9c64909c646bfba31daf6bf8689dc16c9c93180c1602e9d3c', 'file_size': 12195571, 'filename': 'main-win-1.4.zip', 'patch_hash': 'baf3eba3a4b3184919ed9e57c3e8be9494a50862b40b1590ecb64e39e71a4ce3', 'patch_name': 'main-win-6', 'patch_size': 479625}}}}, 'signature': '<redacted>'}
DEBUG:dsdev_utils.helpers:Version str: 1.3
DEBUG:pyupdater.client:Failed version file verification
```

**For those that want to replicate the error for themselves I’ve written the steps I have taken [exactly](https://github.com/tysondogerz/Pyupdater-and-bitbucket-V3/blob/master/Steps%20to%20replicate).**

Comment: This same issue exists with curl also, even if I try a url like that with curl, curl also sends the headers to the next request

Comment: @TarunLalwani Any ideas on how I can remove the basic auth in the header for redirect?  Everything else is fine. that auth is useful for bitbucket not amazon

Comment: Yes, posted the answer for the same. Give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit-1:**

You need use below code for your `main.py` without any changes to `downloader.py`

```
from __future__ import print_function
import urllib3.poolmanager

orig_urlopen = urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager.urlopen


def new_urlopen(self, method, url, redirect=True, **kw):
    if "s3.amazonaws.com" in url and 'authorization' in self.headers:
        self.headers.pop('authorization')
    return orig_urlopen(self, method, url, redirect, **kw)


urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager.urlopen = new_urlopen


import logging

from selenium import webdriver

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
from client_config import ClientConfig
from pyupdater.client import Client, AppUpdate

import http.client as http_client

http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1


def check_for_update():
    client = Client(ClientConfig(), refresh=True, headers={'basic_auth': '<username>:<password>'})
    app_update = client.update_check(ClientConfig.APP_NAME, ClientConfig.APP_VERSION, channel='stable')
    if app_update is not None:
        if app_update.download():
            if isinstance(app_update, AppUpdate):
                app_update.extract_restart()
                return True
            else:
                app_update.extract()
                return True
    return False


def main():
    print('Current version is ', ClientConfig.APP_VERSION)
    if check_for_update():
        print('there\'s a new update :D')
    # driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    # driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**original answer**
You need to use monkey patching for this. Below patch should do the job

```
import urllib3.poolmanager

orig_urlopen = urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager.urlopen


def new_urlopen(self, method, url, redirect=True, **kw):
    if "s3.amazonaws.com" in url and 'Authorization' in self.headers:
        self.headers.pop('Authorization')
    return orig_urlopen(self, method, url, redirect, **kw)


urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager.urlopen = new_urlopen
```

A sample test worked for me with the above patch

```
import urllib3

pool = urllib3.PoolManager()

pool.headers.update({'Authorization': 'Basic XYZ=='})
r = pool.urlopen('GET', 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/keys.gz')
print(r.data)
```

You need to execute the code before import pyupdater

Comment: I'd have to post a pastebin.   Adding the monkey patch, how would data = self.http_pool.urlopen('GET', file_url,
                              preload_content=False,
                              retries=max_download_retries)  look like.  downloading individual files is doable but I need it to update exe

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in monkey patch function and see if it is executed

Comment: I can try add breakpoint but I have not done that before still a newbie here

Comment: Can you post complete code you have used? Looking at your logs, the issue of headers is fixed but you have another issue also

Comment: Sure.  I've posted main.py as well as downloader.py and errors https://pastebin.com/SeLeUZNv

Comment: For readability I also created a github page with files  https://github.com/tysondogerz/Pyupdater-and-bitbucket-V3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163303/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-user9099).

Comment: Thanks.  This updates successfully except no script is run as I  get Nonetype object has no attribute extract https://pastebin.com/NryTG5y5

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and I believe it is a problem with `pyupdater` (I don't know what it is, never used).

It seems to assume that all the response's body will be compressed in GZIP. There is no flag I can find that would prevent this assumption. The actual content is actually not compressed at all.

Here is some relevant code from pyupdater:

`pyupdater/client/__init__.py:`

```
def _get_manifest_from_http(self):
    log.debug('Downloading online version file')
    try:
        fd = _FD(self.version_file, self.update_urls, verify=self.verify,
                 urllb3_headers=self.urllib3_headers)
        data = fd.download_verify_return()
        try:
            import ipdb
            ipdb.set_trace()
            decompressed_data = _gzip_decompress(data)
        except IOError:
            log.debug('Failed to decompress gzip file')
            # Will be caught down below.
            # Just logging the error
            raise
        log.debug('Version file download successful')
        # Writing version file to application data directory
        self._write_manifest_2_filesystem(decompressed_data)
        return decompressed_data
    except Exception as err:
        log.debug('Version file download failed')
        log.debug(err, exc_info=True)
        return None
```

Here is a sample of data I receive:

```
ipdb> data
b'{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "keys.gz"}}'
```

I believe you should open a ticket on https://github.com/JMSwag/PyUpdater and see if they can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is a pretty fantastic library, don't waste time with anything else, unless there is a really good reason:

```
import requests
import zlib

def download(url, username, password):
    r = requests.get(url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
    r.raise_for_status()
    return zlib.decompress(r.content, 15 + 32)

download('https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/brofewfefwefewef/eee/downloads/keys.gz', 'brofewfefwefewef', your_password)
```

Also, it's probably worth noting that the credentials here aren't shouldn't be used anymore. Basic Auth can be decoded pretty simply.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that under the hood pyupdater uses requests.

Comment: Could not create resource url and bytes like object is required not 'None-type'. Error 400 has disappeared though :S